# LWC Application not running outside of salesforce

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-out

Hi I'm new to salesforce, I have one requirement to use my LWC Component outside salesforce, I have searched in google is there any possible way, finally I found one approach to use Lightning out which will meet my requirement.

Then I created project named(DG) and started the developing one simple lightning Web Component named as helloWorld

[image]

In LWC Component I wrote the code below

[image]

Next I created an Aura App which is named like a Sample. In Sample.app I added aura dependency like below
[image]

In the aura app I added dependency to access ‘helloWorld’ LWC Component

Finally I deployed my LWC application in salesforce which is look like this

[image]

Now I Create Asp.net MVC application which is outside of salesforce

I added below javascript code to access LWC Component in my MVC Application

[image]

The above URL is my salesforce org URL

Then I deploy my application in Azure App Service

The application url is added into the CORS and CSP Trusted Sites  in salesforce

When i try to run my MVC application i’m getting error like this below and unable to access LWC Component
[image]

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance.